# Vertically center input placeholder in Chrome

Tags: html, css, input, vertical-alignment, placeholder

Any idea how to vertically center this input field placeholder on Chrome? The input and placeholder font sizes are purposely different. The input placeholder in Firefox and Safari appear vertically centered, but appears lower Chrome.

Here is a sample where you see the centering does not work on Chrome.

```
<input class="input" placeholder="vertical center"/>

.input {
    font-size: 14px;

    &::placeholder {
        font-size: 8px;
        text-align: left;
        color: green;

        // transform-origin: 0% 50%;
        // transform: translate3d(0, -2px, 0);
    }
}
```

Here is a codepen showing the issue:
https://codepen.io/illusionfactory/pen/xxJZrYp?editors=1111

I tried answers from other posts, like transforms on the placeholder, but didn't seem to work.

The translate moves it but then the alignment is not good across all browsers. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
input {
  padding: 12px 2px;
  font-size: 19px;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: green;
  font-size: 8px;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Vertical Center"/>
```

Comment: font sizes can't be removed, so this doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: @1192805 Added the font-size

Comment: the issue in chrome is caused by the input font-size and placeholder font-size being different. your example removes the input font-size but the input font-size is a requirement and cannot be removed

Comment: @1192805 In that case, you can use `position: relative`, and adjust the `top` until it's on the center. See the edit.

Comment: tried this before but it causes the placeholder to move in safari also, which is then not centered. ideally all three browsers would show it vertically centered

Comment: @1192805 I see, the only option I see in that case is to create a custom placeholder by overlapping an element right on top of the input. And hide it when the input is focused.

If the text input can have a transparent background, I'd put the input on top, which would be easier to implement.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem. I had tried various methods, and only this one was correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with css flexbox.

```
    &::placeholder {
margin: 0;
font-size: 11px;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center; 
color: green;
```

}

if u want to know about css flex box please refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container) it may help u.